# Python - Get total amount of bytes used by files

Tags: python, file, filesize, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to get the total amount of bytes used by all files.

What I've got so far is the following.

```
 def getSize(self):
    totalsize = 0
    size = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\\'):
        for files in files:
            size = os.stat(files).st_size
    totalsize = totalsize + size
```

However, when running this, the following error pops up *FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'hiberfil.sys'*

Does anyone know how I can fix this error and correctly calculate the total bytes on the disk?

EDIT: After looking at this some more, I came up with the following code.

```
def getSize():
    print("Getting total system bytes")
    data = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\\'):
        for name in files:
            data = data + getsize(join(root, name))
    print("Total system bytes", data)
```

however I now get the following error. *PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scans\History\CacheManager\MpScanCache-1.bin'*

Comment: Please read more about how `os.walk` works. Then the error message will become more clear. Hint: you might try using `os.path.join()` to build up the full paths to the files.

Comment: Check out [this tutorial](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66455-to-find-out-the-hard-disk-sizefree-space-and-used-/)

Comment: If you are on a recent windows, also take care to handle hard links properly, otherwise the SxS cache will show you wildly wrong numbers, because it contains lots of hardlinks.

Comment: The PermissionError tells you that the user running the script isn't allowed to access the file.  Either run your script as a user that can access the file, or use try...except to catch the exception without exiting your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help:

```
import os
import os.path

def getSize(path):
    totalsize,filecnt = 0,0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path): 
        for file in files:
            tgt=os.path.join(root,file)
            if os.path.exists(tgt): 
                size = os.stat(tgt).st_size
                totalsize = totalsize + size
                filecnt+=1
    return totalsize,filecnt

print '{:,} bytes in {:,} files'.format(*getSize('/Users/droid'))
```

Prints:

```
110,058,100,086 bytes in 449,723 files
```

Or, if it is a permission error, use this:

```
            try:
                size = os.stat(tgt).st_size
                totalsize = totalsize + size
                filecnt+=1
            except (#Permission Error type...): 
                continue
```

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for, thanks :)